# Is it possible to pass a list of value into prepared statement in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement

I can use below sql to define a prepared statement to query a data record:

```
prepare query_data(int) as
    select column1 from table1 where id = $1;
```

but what should I support a list of ids passed into the prepared statement? the list length is uncertain, it can contains of 100 ids or maybe 5000 ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array:

```
PREPARE stmt(int[]) AS SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE id =ANY ($1);

EXECUTE stmt(ARRAY[1,2]);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly.

Can I use `in` in the prepared statement?

I tried this but it doesn't work because `$1` is an array, then ($1) is a set of array.

`prepare query_data(int[]) as select column1 from table1 where id in ($1);`

How can I pass in a set of int and then use `where id in $1`?

Comment: You cannot do that. But you shouldn't need to: internally, PostgreSQL translates `IN` to `= ANY` anyway.